# Kill Eclipse background operation without killing Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to kill an Eclipse background operation without killing Eclipse itself?

Specifically, I want to kill stalled Subclipse SVN operations.  Clicking 'cancel' pops up a little *Cancel Requested* message, but the operation still sits there forever blocking everything else.

This is Eclipse Helios on Windows 7 if that makes any difference.

Comment: It's freaking 2017 and I have the same problem!

Comment: @GradDev now it has been 2018 and i'm stuck at it!

Comment: It is now 2018 and I have the same problem!  The joys of eclipse!

Comment: 2019.. and the same :(

Comment: 2020 and still the same problem]

Comment: 2021 ...... it ... can't ... initialize .. the .. java ... tooling ...

Comment: late 2021...same issue (on win10..) .. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Killing the task from the Progress window (Window->Show View->Other|General->Progress or Alt+Shift+Q, Q | General->Progress).

Then choose the offending thread and click the red square.

Note it sometimes takes a delay before the kill occur, you may also have to kill other thread in there to get what you want. Lastly it does not always work, if this fails I usually just restart eclipse.

Hope this helps

Comment: Cheers, but that's what I'm doing - it just says _Cancel Requested_ until I give up and kill Eclipse :(

Comment: yeah, not all plugins are developed equally.  I am stuck using the TFS eclipse plugin and often times it just get stuck on a file on a modal commit dialog with the cancel greyed out....  Perhaps using a different SVN plugin would be of service.

Comment: I have the same problem with hanging "SVN Commits" cancel requests. It hangs on the CANCEL request, not the commit itself!

Comment: FWIW: Switching to another SVN extension probably won't help.  I've seen the same problem with Subversive.  Subclipse is much better, of course.  I suspect it's not a problem with the extensions.  It's something to do with Eclipse itself.

Comment: yes, it does not always work and the problem is indeed not limited to a specif SVN plugin or to SVN at all.  Many plugins will have this defect, some even go as far as creating a modal window with the cancel button grayed out ... sight...  [Much like society](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) in general not all plugins know their place.

Comment: Yes, the last part in the answer really helped "close the eclipse". LoL. But even after closing the eclipse, the last process which I wanted to kill is still trying to "cancel". What a bad design!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

I was able to unstuck Eclipse (it was stuck on a large file diff) using the following steps.

- Preparations: I always start Eclipse with the eclipse-console: Add start parameter **-console** in **eclipse.ini** (first line)
- The console always remains responsive even when the eclipse UI freezes
- I found the following commands in the console: **help threads**
- List all threads: **threads**
- Stop a thread: **threads stop THREAD-NAME**

**UPDATE:** I found out, that usually the "main" thread causes the freezing. **Thus the solution is:**

**Type this in the eclipse console:**

```
threads stop main
```

This will trigger/throw an Exception in that thread, effectively interrupting what it was doing (being stuck).

This *might* cause other side-effects (depending on what action was interrupted and where), but i had no problems with it so far.

Comment: You made my day. This finally allows to kill hung builds or connections without killing the process

Answer (score 5):

I was able to stop/terminate the hanging SVN commit process by briefly disconnecting the network adapter. This saved me from killing the Eclipse process, which if not terminated gracefully is known to cause other headaches.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to window Progress in Eclipse and click red square to Stop:

[image: Stopping Wildfly 9.x]

and next, red square becomes gray square and process i frozen (Cancel Requested):

[image: eStopping Wildfly 9.x Cancel Requested]

You must use Task Manager (Alt+Ctrl+Del on Windows) for **kill process**. Go to tab Processes, find process `javaw.exe`* and click End Process.

The result: frozen process in Eclipse was closed but your Eclipse wasn't closed.

* Process with name `javaw.exe` is for WildFly server. For Subclipse SVN can be another name of proces.

Comment: `javaw.exe` is not for WildFly :) It's just java process without a console attached.

Comment: Killing `javaw.exe` helped me because it happens that killing Eclipse leaves a fool "Progress information" dialog with the stuck process waiting to end. I wasn't able to find the process to kill to remove that dialog. Well, it's `javaw.exe`, which in fact is what Eclipse does when summoning tasks: launch console-less java process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but from the Debug perspective, you may be able to view the thread that's performing the background operation and kill it from there for quicker exit.

Answer (score 1):

In console window, open "Open OSGi Console" from drop button.
In this console you can type command `threads`. This will show all running threads.
You can kill process with command `threads stop '<Process name>'`. Remember to use single apostrophe `'` surrounding `<Process name>`, otherwise it won't work.

For example, I had to type:

```
threads stop 'Worker-12: Refresh DSLD scripts'
```

Comment: useful but is there a way to findout thread for stuck "cancel requested"?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @NaiveCoder - Check Frederic Leitenberger's comment

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where the external compiler I was using froze up when I tried to cancel the build operation. It was stuck in the "Cancel Requested" state. I went to the Windows Task Manager and found my compiler process and terminated it. That allowed Eclipse to continue and successfully cancel the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Keep clicking on clean console, it will show the back ground processes,  keep killing one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I made this by opening console in eclipse and typing 'threads'. And then 'threads stop thread-name'.

Answer (score 0):

In Lunux you can list all the Eclipse processes

```
ps -edf | grep eclipse
```

Then you choose the child process (the backgound doing Java process) of the main process (the Eclipse GUI Java process) of the starting shell process.

Example:

```
myself   21821  1222  0 09:28 ?    00:00:00 /local/eclipse/jee-2021-06/eclipse
myself   21839 21821  8 09:28 ?    00:24:53 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace ... much more ...
myself   21965 21839  0 09:29 ?    00:01:48 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -cp /local/eclipse/jee-2021-06/eclipse/../../../../home/myself/.p2/pool/p ... much more ...
```

The child in the chain of processes is the one with the `proc-id` 21965. This one you have to kill.
Try `kill -2 <proc-id>` and, if it did not work, `kill -9 <procid>`